# Identify the Peer/Org executing the chaincode from within the chaincode [Fabric 1.2 or 1.3]

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am working with private data collections (PDC) and trying to set up a separate PDC for each org with only 1 member (i.e the org itself). 
For example, in a 3 org network, I am looking to create 3 private data collections:

1) "org1-private" with only Org1 as member, 
2) "org2-private" with only Org2 as member, 
3) "org3-private" with only Org3 as member

When a transaction is invoked by the client, the data needs to be shared only between 2 orgs. The client app will send the transaction to the 2 relevant Org peers, but in the chaincode, to write to the correct PDC on a given org the chaincode needs to know which Org/Peer it is executing on.

What is the best way to find the current peer/org from inside the chaincode in Fabric 1.2?

Note: I understand PDCs with all possible pairs of Orgs can be created to solve this issue. In my experiment, there is a strict requirement NOT to create private data collections per pair.

- tried calling GetLocalMSP from the package: "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/msp/mgmt" but it returns a memory address
- GetLocalMSP().GetIdentifier() returns `nil`

  import (
    mspmgmt "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/msp/mgmt"
  )

  fmt.Println(mspmgmt.GetLocalMSP())  // prints mem-address
  id, _ := mspmgmt.GetLocalMSP().GetIdentifier()
  fmt.Println(id)   // prints `nil`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Client Identity Chaincode Library.

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/tree/master/core/chaincode/lib/cid

This will return the MSPID from the certificate invoking the chaincode:

```
mspid, err := cid.GetMSPID(stub)
```